# Format Time stamp in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm getting a formatting error..

My code:

```
date,bid,ask = np.loadtxt('EURUSDH1_1week1.csv', unpack=True, delimiter=',', converters={0:mdates.strpdate2num('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')})
```

error:

> ValueError: time data '20180406,00:48.9,1.22394,1.22417,,"' does not match format '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'

The data in the csv file is shown as (four columns):

```
20180406    00:48.9 1.22394 1.22417
20180406    00:48.9 1.22394 1.22417
20180406    00:53.3 1.2239  1.22421
20180406    00:54.6 1.22391 0
20180406    01:51.8 0       1.2241
20180406    02:19.4 1.22396 1.22404
20180406    02:49.8 1.22391 1.22399
```

how do i remove the colons and period from the time stamp?

Comment: Could you paste a few lines of the csv file, verbatim?

Comment: 20180406 00:48.9 1.22394 1.22417
20180406 00:53.3 1.2239 1.22421
20180406 00:54.6 1.22391 
20180406 01:51.8  1.2241
20180406 02:19.4 1.22396 1.22404
20180406 02:49.8 1.22391 1.22399

Comment: Paste it in the question. It won't display correctly if pasted as part of the comments.

Comment: So first of all, if those lines are verbatim from your csv file, then you can't use `numpy.loadtxt`. `numpy.loadtxt` can't deal with rows that may have missing values (as demonstrated by the 4th and 5th rows).

You would have to use `numpy.genfromtxt`.

Comment: oh okay that makes sense, you're right i'll have to fill in those columns

Comment: Secondly, your delimiter is not a comma, but the space character.

Comment: And you need to ensure that `numpy.genfromtxt` can unambiguously and correctly tell which column is missing data. E.g. in the 5th row, is data missing from the 3rd column or from the 4th column? `numpy.genfromtxt` will treat contigous whitespaces as *one* delimiter.

Comment: i tried using a space but i get the same error for the format, using delimiter = ' '

Comment: can i use data = pd.read_csv('EURUSDH1_1week1.csv')
data = data.fillna(method='ffill') to fill the empty space?

Comment: `pd.read_csv` would be subject to similar limitations. Do you have control over the format of the csv file? Can you get it generated using an unambiguous delimiter?

Comment: Yes, i made the CSV file.  i have four columns as Date, Time, Bid, Ask, a fairly simple file.  Can i format the CSV so that its one column with each of the four features separated by a comma?  I'm not sure if that makes it easier.

Comment: Yes, that should make your life easier. And then you can use `pd.read_csv` or `np.genfromtxt`.

Comment: Okay, so i was able to fill all the blank cells with 0 and changed to pd.read_csv but i received the same error

Comment: so i updated the question but i noticed an extra comma and quote at the end of the row if i open the csv as a txt file in Notepad.  I think that's why the format error is being generated from the code.  But i don't know how to remove the extra comma and quote

Comment: Then you first need to fix your CSV generation. Is that also generated using Python?

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` is good for many things. But for mixed type data `pandas` is usually more convenient.

This is one way you can convert your data to `datetime` using `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO("""20180406    00:48.9 1.22394 1.22417
20180406    00:48.9 1.22394 1.22417
20180406    00:53.3 1.2239  1.22421
20180406    00:54.6 1.22391 0
20180406    01:51.8 0       1.2241
20180406    02:19.4 1.22396 1.22404
20180406    02:49.8 1.22391 1.22399""")

# replace mystr with 'file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(mystr, delim_whitespace=True, header=None,
                 names=['Date', 'Time', 'Bid', 'Ask'])

# create datetime  column
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].map(str) + ' ' + df['Time'])

print(df)

#        Date     Time      Bid      Ask            DateTime
# 0  20180406  00:48.9  1.22394  1.22417 2018-04-06 00:48:53
# 1  20180406  00:48.9  1.22394  1.22417 2018-04-06 00:48:53
# 2  20180406  00:53.3  1.22390  1.22421 2018-04-06 00:53:17
# 3  20180406  00:54.6  1.22391  0.00000 2018-04-06 00:54:36
# 4  20180406  01:51.8  0.00000  1.22410 2018-04-06 01:51:47
# 5  20180406  02:19.4  1.22396  1.22404 2018-04-06 02:19:23
# 6  20180406  02:49.8  1.22391  1.22399 2018-04-06 02:49:47
```

Data types in result:

```
print(df.dtypes)

# Date                 int64
# Time                object
# Bid                float64
# Ask                float64
# DateTime    datetime64[ns]
# dtype: object
```

Comment: Hello jpp, that is very helpful and i will add this to my code, but the original question was to remove the period and colon from the time stamp so i just have numbers.  Or, is there a way to use the Time in the current format as a float to use in for loops

Comment: You can just use `df['DateTime'] = df['DateTime'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')` after you have created a `datetime` series.